# Shibboleth Path exclusion

Tags: path, shibboleth

We have a web site that is using shibboleth. I need to exclude a portion from being protected.
So far the only way I can get this to work is by excluding an entire top level directory.
If I exclude using this things work properly.
Path name="rxxx_v10.0.25/" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="false"

When I look at the sites using developer tools I see rxx_v10.0.25/ExternalModules and rxx_v10.0.25/Resources being accessed. If I specify those paths only the URLs end up being protected instead of not being protected.
I have tried the exclusions in various order, alphabetically or in the order that they are accessed, but am having no luck.

Any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.